# "First order by" in Teradata

Tags: sql, oracle, teradata, row-number

I have a problem converting SQL statement from Oracle to Teradata. In Oracle statement is that:

```
SELECT ar.account_no,
MAX (ah.bal_acct) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY ah.created_t desc) 
FROM ar
   JOIN ah ON ah.obj_id0 = ar.poid_Id0
   JOIN acc ON a.poid_id0 = ar.account_obj_Id0
WHERE acc.account_no = '1234'
AND ah.created_t <= 1434753495
GROUP BY ar.account_no
```

I need to do similar statement in Teradata. I tried something with

```
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY max(ah.bal_acct) ORDER BY ah.created_t desc) = 1
```

But all the time I have error: Selected non-aggregate values must be part of the associated group.

This is what I got:

```
Select ar.account_no, ah.created_t, ah.bal_acct
FROM VD_REPLICA_BRM.pi_tp_acct_ar_t ar
    JOIN VD_REPLICA_BRM.pi_tp_acct_ar_hist_T ah ON ah.obj_id0 = ar.poid_Id0
    JOIN VD_REPLICA_BRM.pi_account_t acc ON acc.poid_id0 = ar.account_obj_Id0
WHERE acc.account_no = '00003095660515'
    AND ah.created_t <= CAST('2016-10-31' AS DATE FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD')
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY max(ah.bal_acct) ORDER BY ah.created_t desc) = 1
GROUP BY ar.account_no
```

Where do I do mistake?

Comment: `ah.created_t <= date '2016-10-31'`. This is the ANSI/ISO notation for date literals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can do this with `qualify`.  An equivalent statement is:

```
SELECT ar.account_no, ah.created_t, ah.bal_acct
FROM (SELECT ar.account_no, ah.created_t, ah.bal_acct,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ar.account_no ORDER BY ah.created_t DESC) as seqnum
      FROM ar JOIN
           ah
           ON ah.obj_id0 = ar.poid_Id0 JOIN
           acc
           ON a.poid_id0 = ar.account_obj_Id0
      WHERE acc.account_no = '1234' AND ah.created_t <= 1434753495
     ) t
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Duh.  You can do this with `QUALIFY`.  The issue is the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT ar.account_no, ah.created_t, ah.bal_acct
FROM VD_REPLICA_BRM.pi_tp_acct_ar_t ar JOIN
     VD_REPLICA_BRM.pi_tp_acct_ar_hist_T ah
     ON ah.obj_id0 = ar.poid_Id0 JOIN
     VD_REPLICA_BRM.pi_account_t acc
     ON acc.poid_id0 = ar.account_obj_Id0
WHERE acc.account_no = '00003095660515' AND
      ah.created_t <= CAST('2016-10-31' AS DATE FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD')
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY ar_account_no ORDER BY ah.created_t desc) = 1
```